# Reload a gif image on a page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

My website have a div with a gif image as background.

The gif animation will be played on the first loading. When page refresh or redirect to the home page from another page there will be no animation. I have to play the gif image whenever landing on home page. How can i reload the animation? Please anyone provide a solution.

Comment: Check the below link that may be useful to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455788/gif-animation-not-playing-on-refresh

Comment: I have used image as background

Comment: you can't control the animation of the images

Answer (score 0):

Use java-script cookies as flag variables to determine when to load the animation .gif accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
<style>
    #page-loader {
        position: fixed !important;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: #000 url(&#39;http://i.imgur.com/pKopwXp.gif&#39;) no-repeat 50% 30%;
        color: #FFF;
        display: none;
        font: 0/0 a;
        text-shadow: none;
        padding: 1em 1.2em;
    }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document.body).append('<div id="page-loader">Loading...</div>');
    $(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
        $('#page-loader').fadeIn(1000).delay(6000).fadeOut(1000);
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Change `http://i.imgur.com/pKopwXp.gif` to your image URL.